# `find` return value: Is the find man page wrong?

Tags: find, exit-status

The `find` man page says:

> `-execdir command {} +` always  returns  true,  while  `-execdir  command  {}  ;`
>                 returns true only if command returns 0.

and

> **EXIT STATUS**
>          find exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur.

But if I test this, I get the opposite behaviour:

```
 $ find . -execdir false '{}' \; ; echo $?      
 0

 $ find . -execdir false '{}' \+ ; echo $?      
 1
```

Can someone explain this?

With `-exec` instead of `-execdir` I get the same results. I tried `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0` and `4.4.2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This "return" isn't the exit code of `find`, but the return value of the `-execdir` action for the purposes of chaining multiple `find` actions together. If you try:

```
find . -execdir false '{}' \; -print
```

then `-print` never executes (that is, there is no output), while both of:

```
find . -execdir true '{}' \; -print
find . -execdir false '{}' + -print
```

print every path.

---

However, when using a `+` the exit code of `find` *is* set: it is non-zero if any invocation of the command exits non-zero, while for a `;` the exit code is unaffected (directly) by the command results. This behaviour [is required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) for `-exec`, I suppose to indicate failures that would otherwise be undetectable:

> If the primary expression is punctuated by a `<plus-sign>`, the primary shall always evaluate as true, and the pathnames for which the primary is evaluated shall be aggregated into sets. [...] **If any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status, the find utility shall return a non-zero exit status**.

`-exec ... \;` is not specified as affecting the exit code, so `find`'s default behaviour of exiting zero unless there was an error applies. An `-exec ... \;` command exiting non-zero is not regarded as an error, so in the absence of some other error the exit code will always be zero.

Comment: Thanks! The exit status 0 if "All path operands were traversed successfully." of the POSIX is also more precise than the GNU man page ("0 if all files processed successfully").